# Check first condition in IF and test in the next statement too in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'd like to understand something in Python - IF condition.
Using this example code:

```
num = 1

if (num == 1):
    print ("op 1")
elif (num < 2):
    print ("op 2")
elif (num <= 1):
    print ("op 3")
elif (num != 1):
    print ("op 4")
else:
    print ("Fail")

print ("End")
```

I'll get the first condition and then go to the end.

How can I do it to check, for example, the first and if True go check the next condition too? And check all of them?

Trying to use CONTINUE not worked; I used a bunch of IFs instead of IF->Elif, but is this the right way to do?

Comment: Just replace the `elif` with `if`?

Comment: `if: ... if: ...` is something different than `if: ... elif: ...`. This difference is deliberate and there so you can pick and choose what you need. One isn't better or more correct than the other. Simply write what you mean. It's not complicated.

Comment: Do you want to check each condition independently, or only check each if the one before it is `True`? What about the `else`; how should that behave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I used a bunch of IFs instead of IF->Elif, but is this the right way to do?

This is exactly the right way to do it. Any time an if statement is true, the remaining elif statements are skipped. The only way to ensure that all are checked is with if statements.

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate `if` statement for each condition. However, you need to keep track of when a condition applies to handle the case where *none* are true in order to print "Fail".

```
num = 1

none = True

if (num == 1):
    print ("op 1")
    none = False
if (num < 2):
    print ("op 2")
    none = False
if (num <= 1):
    print ("op 3")
    none = False
if (num != 1):
    print ("op 4")
    none = False
if none:
    print ("Fail")

print ("End")
```

This can also be re-ordered to be a little more efficient.

```
ops = [False, False, False, False]
if num < 2:
    ops[1] = True
    if num <= 1:
        ops[2] = True
        if num == 1:
            ops[0] = True
if num != 1:
    ops[3] = False

if any(ops):
    for num, op in enumerate(ops):
        if op:
            print("op %d" % (num+1))
else:
    print("Fail")
```

(Note that in this code, you would never print `Fail`, since `num` either is or isn't equal to 1, and both cases are caught.)